# Checking if cell note exist

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following script to add the value entered and a timestamp as a cell note to the adjacent cell and then clear the value entered cell:

```
switch (comments) {
  case  "":
    comments = "(" + timestamp + ") " + cellValue;
    adjacent.setComment(comments);
    changedRange.clearContent();
    break;
  default:
    comments = comments + "\n" + "(" + timestamp + ") " + cellValue;
    adjacent.setComment(comments);
    changedRange.clearContent();
    break;}
```

It's working fine but it's just running the default case each time because the script is not seeing a note-less cell (case "":). This isn't a big problem but I would prefer for there to not be a space above the first line of the note when notes are added to a note-less cell. I also tried using an if then else statement but couldn't get it to work

```
if (comments == "") {
     comments = "(" + timestamp + ") " + cellValue;
     adjacent.setComment(comments);
     changedRange.clearContent(); }
  else if (comments != "") {
     comments = comments + "\n" + "(" + timestamp + ") " + cellValue;
     adjacent.setComment(comments);
     changedRange.clearContent(); }
```

Is there a better way to do this or a way to check for a note-less cell? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second bit of code was the answer. The complete code:

```
function revTime(event){
  var ColCR = 96;  // Column Number of "CR"

  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColCR) {
    // An edit has occurred in Column CR
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColCR+1);
    var comments = adjacent.getComments();
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "M/dd/yy', 'h:mm a"); // Get the current time
    // We'll do something different, depending on the selected value
     if (comments == "") {
     comments = "(" + timestamp + ") " + state;
     adjacent.setComment(comments);
     changedRange.clearContent(); }
    else if (comments != "") {
     comments = comments + "\n" + "(" + timestamp + ") " + state;
     adjacent.setComment(comments);
     changedRange.clearContent(); } 
  }
}
```